# How to remove native mac title bar on a Java Swing app

Tags: java, macos, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I have a quick question that I don't think I've seen before on stack exchange. This might be due in part to me not knowing what to ask, but regardless I thought I'd post a question with the wording I'd use for any other beginners.

My question is related to the UI design of a Java Swing application. I am using the NetBeans GUI designer to quickly lay out my idea, but as I am doing it on a mac, I'm not a big fan of the native "close, minimize, expand" buttons.

[image: example picture]

I would like to achieve something similar to the discord style which looks like this.

[image: desired appearance]

It doesn't have to be exactly the same but I'm just trying to get an idea for what I would do.

I'm mainly just looking for pointers into where I would go about finding the information to do this as I would like to actually gain some knowledge from this. (As opposed to having you just fix my code)

Any help is greatly appreciated and I look forward to your responses; thanks.

Comment: If you don't want the title bar of your form to be displayed then you can simply set the JFrame **undecorated** property. In the properties panel for your JFrame form simply place a checkmark in the **undecorated** property. This will remove the title bar and border from your form. You can now create your own title bar type and set your own border style.

Comment: That's a title bar, not a menu bar.  I have no idea how to do it with Java but you might have more luck searching for this term.

Comment: Write your own look and feel delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove the title bar using **undecorated** property in your JFrame properties.

Just go to properties and check the **undecorated** as checked.
Then you have use your custom designed title bar with "close","maximize" and "minimize" buttons or what you like and you have to code for mouse pointer to drag the Frame to any location in screen.

[image]